# Redhat linux: Slow start of new socket connections

Tags: redhat, tcp, socket

I am having problems with a Red Hat server  2.6.18.
The creation of  a new TCP socket takes very long - once it is established it is fine. iptables and selinux are disabled - is there any other service which needs to be stopped?
Oddly enough I see the problem with Windows machines only.

Comment: That sounds strange. Have you tried TCPDump to see what's really going on ?

Comment: With which parameters should I use Tcpdump? I did not see my traffic as expected. The establishment of the traffic takes exactly 20 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using ssh, add the following to /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
UseDNS no
```

Comment: I am using simple tcp sockets on the application level - I have changed the sshd_config anyway with no effect.

Comment: You pointed me into the right direction - after adding the machines into the hosts file, the problem is gone.